# Unable to load Google Colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

On trying to open a new or existing Google Colab notebook, it does not load.
[Colab in Chrome browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBIHa.png)

Further, the console log shows following 2  errors and 1 issue.
First error:

Recording uncaught error: TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
(anonymous) @ external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:1590

Second Error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at editor.main.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:6 at editor.main.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:546 at Function.r._invokeFactory (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:8) at r.complete (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:8) at r._onModuleComplete (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:9) at r._onModuleComplete (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:9) at r._onModuleComplete (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:9) at r._onModuleComplete (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:9) at r._resolve (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:9) at r.defineModule (loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:8)`

Colab does not work with either Chrome or Firefox. I am using Chrome Browser Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit). Also, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS 64-Bit.

[Image of Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Dxa.png)

Please help. Thank-you.

Comment: Is this just an error you are getting on a particular webpage?

Comment: @IainShelvington No, I am getting this error with both new notebooks and existing ones (In Google Drive) which I try to open using my colab account.

Comment: I am also facing this exact same issue. Wondering what's the exact cause for it.

Comment: EDIT: As of 1 day from the issue, it no longer persists, though, it would be interesting to understand what had happened. There is nothing that I did about it.